# Cannot add new NSManagedObject into CoreData using Swift convenience initializer

Tags: swift, core-data

I try to learn a modern approach to CoreData and I have written this chunk of code to save new records to CoreData:

```
    @IBAction func saveTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        guard let context = persistentContainer?.viewContext else { return }
        guard let newSettings = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Settings", into: context) as? Settings else { return }

        newSettings.ingredients = self.ingredients.rawValue

        self.saveData()
    }
```

It works fine but I think that I should use convenience Initializer of my `Settings` class, like this:

```
    @IBAction func saveTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        guard let context = persistentContainer?.viewContext else { return }

        let newSettings = Settings(context: context)
        newSettings.ingredients = self.ingredients.rawValue

        context.insert(newSettings)
        self.saveData()
}
```

However, this is not working. When I re-run my App I don't see my changes being loaded (and I load `Settings` in `viewDidLoad()` to setup UI).

Am I missing something?

Comment: In the second example delete the line `context.insert(newSettings)`. The API `Settings(context:)` inserts the object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why by removing the `context.insert(newSettings)` helped.
So valid code looks like this:

```
   @IBAction func saveTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    guard let context = persistentContainer?.viewContext else { return }

    let newSettings = Settings(context: context)
    newSettings.ingredients = self.ingredients.rawValue

    self.saveData()
}
```